# Is there CORS enabled or disabled?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

I have config like this `http.cors().and().csrf().disable().` Is there both cors and csrf disabled or is cors enabled and crsf disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case just CSRF is disabled. You have to disable both explictly.

```
http.cors().disable();
http.csrf().disable();
```